# What is the recommended jmeter listener to use during a load test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am performing an http load test (`~1000rpm`).

I want to be able to view some results (like `avg throughput`, `avg response time`, etc...)

I see in documentation on many listeners:

> during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU).
>   Use it only for either functional testing or during Test Plan
>   debugging and Validation.

So is there any listener that I can use during an actual load test? (that won't consume much resources)?

Comment: Summary report is not bad, I had it handle ~300 users / 10k requests per minute, but I do configure the runner for that specifically: separate virtual disk for the log + jmeter's java memory set to about 8Gb xmx.
Aggregate report is less efficient, and what you definitely want to avoid is the result tree.

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended that you use run load test in non-ui mode. Collect the samples and then use different listeners once you have the raw results with you. Running from UI mode consumes resources and having listeners added while test is going on is overhead for JMeter.

You can use tests in non-ui mode like: `jmeter.bat -n -t script_name -l log_file.jtl`

This will record all the samples in `log_file.jtl`.

You can use following listeners to analyze the results:

```
 1. Summary Report
 2. Aggregate report
 3. Throughput Listener
```

There are some additional listeners that you can get from https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/. They help you with better analysis. I normally use `Response Time Over Time` and `Transactions Per Second`.